# How to bind oninput event in angularjs to check for maxlength?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input

I am trying to validate maxlength for input field oninput event. I have javascript code working for validation but I need help how can I implement in angular.

I know, this can be done with controller but Input fields has controller already which checks for non numeric value (avoid letter).

Please advice whats the best approach.

javaScript which checks maxlength oninput event

```
  function maxLengthCheck(object) {
    if (object.value.length > object.maxLength)
      object.value = object.value.slice(0, object.maxLength)
  }
```

HTML

```
<input type="number"
           min="1"
           max="9"
           maxlength="10"
           oninput="maxLengthCheck(this)"
           class="form-control value"
           ng-model="apr.VPR.value"
           ng-controller="formValidationController"
           >
```

Comment: you have input type number so set max accordingly. maxlength does not work with input type number.

Comment: @PSL yea, it doesnt not work. I want it to be type=number because tablets/ipad will enforces number keypad when its type=number

Comment: You could do max=999999999 and have a validation on the input. otherwise you would need to create a directive to strip off extra

Comment: if you want at least want to alert the user that the maximum length has been exceeded, then you may be able to use: `"ng-maxlength="10"` , and if you had, for example, `<form name="myForm"..>` and `<input name="myInput"..>` then you can evaluate this input by using `myForm.myInput.$error.maxlength`